# soup.find(class_="" ) not working and return NoneType, in this case, how to scrape the website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website so as to download the names and links of all coins listed on the website: https://www.cryptocompare.com/ico/#/completed

I tried using the beautifulsoup module to locate the div class=coins-list and then the

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url= "https://www.cryptocompare.com/ico/#/completed"
r=session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

coin_name_list = soup.find("div",attrs= {"id":"coins-list"})
coin_name_list_items = coin_name_list.find_all('a')
```

The error message is as follows:
---> 14 coin_name_list_items = coin_name_list.find_all('a')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

I don't understand why this isn't working, is it sth related to the website or the programming? It would be much appreciated if anyone can find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScripts render the page.However if you go Network Tab you will get below api which returns output as json

```
url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/subsWatchlist?fsyms=433,ABT,DRG,XTZ,FIL,BNT,SPICE,ALGO,SRN,PMA,SNT,SOLID,WAX,NTK,BKX,DRT,EVN,ONL,OIO,LDC,CEL,BUBO,SVD,DOR,ICX,INS,LAX,GAT,NGC,WPR,OKOIN,HBZ,BQTX,MTH,PAT,BAT,AST,OMX,INVC,C20,POWR,FUEL,REQ,CVC,AGI,AMB,LINK,BRD,PLBT,SYNCO,STORJ,MWAT,LUC,CRE,CMT,BMC,BERRY,redBUX,RAC,MCO,DLT,STX,SFU,TCOIN,RKT,MANA,OAK,SNM,FUN,WRC,BCAT,VRA,CFTY,TNT,PROPS,OMG,ANT,AE,EDO,SETH,WT,TIOX,CMCT,ENJ,EVX,KICK,COV,ZUP,PLR,VEE,BDG,KEY,STT,U42,UTK,AID,AVT,IMPCN,TFLEX,SLX,PLA,ISR,GARD,FLUZ,BAX,RVT,CSP,HOLO,MCAP,THO,VLR,TFD,WBBC,ELY,DBCCOIN,LA,OAX,DAV,ETH,OST,DMT,GLDR,IHT,FLP,CTR,ILCT,BEX,CTLX,ATOM,NAVI,CEDEX,EVC,TPAY,WAVES,WELL,WHN,LYK,eQUAD,HHEM,GENE,APPC,MASP,LAMB,ABYSS,QTUM,PHX,EKO,DTR,CPAY,COFI,CEEK,BIT,AIR,ATB,CFI,HQX,PRO,PIX,NEU,GES,ART,NIM,MYST,ICOS,SLY,ORS,HST,FOAM,DEB,OSA,TMT,GFT,LEV,COB,TKN,HGS,GNO,GLA,DAOC,NPX,BOS,XCD,RLC,VERI,ADB,LCK,LCS,EARTH,MOAT,BNTN,FSBT,SUB,WLK,HOLD,DTH,ELI,NRN,CIX100,PST,DNO,ACAT,ROX,VIB,FIII,ICN,MFG,CJT,BCNX,REAL,CSNO,XYO,SAN,PTOY,MTRC,XRL,TAU,POE,KRM,GBXT,BCNA,BCAP,IMVR,DIM,ESTATE,BON,ARAW,IND,VCN,ADM,EXY,DNT,AMO,CPY,ADX,GC,HAC,PPT,MTL,BITX,CAS,DRGN,PAN,CUZ,PKT,SEAL,SHPING,GNT,HVN,LED,YMZ,LTA,CTX,EBC,BITCAR,GAMB,GMA,STAC,DUSK,GENS,SRXIO,DTN,PBT,KEP,ADT,BBI,MNTP,CAN,TAAS,LWF,DAY,CCOS,DAT,SNGLS,CDT,KNW,AEN,WIZ,BFC,SHP,ZRC,EQUI,TIX,IXT,ERT,MLT,SPX,VTM,PROOF,ECHT,INDI,SCL,UBEX,HBT,TIE,MAID,WGR,LSK,GBE,ATL,ETRNT,ITM,ARR,LOCI,DLA,MIO,FNX,AZ,TFL,GJC,JVY,SCRM,MOLK,DGD,1ST,X8X,GUAR,TIME,AUC,EON,ORBIS,HGT,HMQ,XID,REP,MSP,VIN,STA,DRP,ALX,TAN,GUP,JOY,ACE,VZT,VNS,CAPP,XELS,AIC,MEM,REPUX,AMP,TRW,TRST,ARN,XBB,OXY,SRCH,PPY,ECOB,FUNDP,ETT,HETA,LYM,FLOT,DENT,DCT,QAU,XRM,PLC,SFT,COIN,SRNT,NVST,PINMO,CVCOIN,NEO,ADST,DTX,IPT,DIP,GBA,BTS,PKC,CHT,CHX,LUN,JOYT,GRO,CLIN,SKIN,MNRB,QRL,MOS,MOBU,NRX,COTI,YUM,MYDFS,WINS,H2O,MLN,IAG,VESTA,OSF,GBTC,MYB,TASH,CRON,SUR,T4M,CAP,EDG,ICOO,VANM,PSK,ALTOCAR,PING,ICE,FNP,DNN,ICST,LNT,PHM,UNITY,RCC,VRT,BCCOIN,OCEANT,MT,IFT,COS,LAT,CRL,ILT,SAT,STU,SNOV,PRIX,HMT,ARNA,COR,WINGS,LGD,CYBR,AXIS,KMD,ITT,MTX,OMI,LYQD,GAI,ENCX,DDF,WRL,ETE,XCP,GMR,TOSS,ET4,VSL,ETKN,TKT,SNC,PYP,RYZ,FDX,ATFS,GEA,LNK,TJA,SND,BTRM,IGTT,AMBT,FILL,VOISE,AUDC,REA,AUK,ATTR,GIM,CRS,DNA,NEBL,CTW,BETHER,AUN,DHT,LKK,ETBS,FYN,INCNT,BAY,DTB,TRIP,ADL,ADUX,GUESS,MBI,PLU,DRC,ARK,SRC,EMT,HDG,SRX,KEX,FFCT,KVNT,PART,QVT,DGPT,COT,SREUR,ROCK,KAPU,TUT,ENK,PQT,CWEX,STRAT,RKC,NFN,SWARM,NBX,WAND,TFC,DTRC,SAF,OMNI,MAT,HBX,EMN,EJAC,FNTB,SPEND,FOXT,GOLOS,SJCX,DSLA,ATON,UMC,AVA,PRP,SDAO,NXC,KEN,VIA,TKR,CHK,VEGA,ORI,ZOPT,TWC,RIYA,CREA,GXC,ROCK2,JDC,DAR,DTCT,WEB,PERU,JSE,PGL,HELIOS,OTX,MC,ODMC,GGS,CFT,ABC,VTOS,CCT,FLLW,SGN,SIFT,CRTM,PRM,CO2,BOU,ITR,SNK,CZC,AHT,AGVC,XRX,SYC,3DES,LTCH,CPL,NIMFA,TRAVEL,SCOR,BNR,TKS,UET,XTRA,MNM,XLC,XCJ,PLMT,MEDI,CWX,IWT,PSB,SPORTG,XSPEC,ICOB,SMNX,KRP,NXT,EQ,ROK,AFCT,TRIBE,Z2,DFBT,OXY2,MIOTA,ZYM,ZUC,ZRX,ZNT,ZNAQ,ZNA,ZIX,ZILLA,ZEROB,ZEEW,ZCHN,ZCC1,ZAZA,ZAB,YSH,YPTO,YDY,YBT,YANU,YACHTCO,XUC,XTN,XSB,XRK,XRF,XRED,XRBT,XR,XPX,XPT,XPR,XPL,XOS,XNT,XIM,XGH,XEP,XDT,XCZ,XBX,XBOND,XBANK,XAL,WYR,WXT,WUG,WU,WTXH,WTT,WTL,WSH,WRT,WPT,WPP,WOWX,WORK,WOM,WMK,WMD,WMB,WLME,WIIX,WICC&tsym=USD"
```

Import json to use that json object.

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/subsWatchlist?fsyms=433,ABT,DRG,XTZ,FIL,BNT,SPICE,ALGO,SRN,PMA,SNT,SOLID,WAX,NTK,BKX,DRT,EVN,ONL,OIO,LDC,CEL,BUBO,SVD,DOR,ICX,INS,LAX,GAT,NGC,WPR,OKOIN,HBZ,BQTX,MTH,PAT,BAT,AST,OMX,INVC,C20,POWR,FUEL,REQ,CVC,AGI,AMB,LINK,BRD,PLBT,SYNCO,STORJ,MWAT,LUC,CRE,CMT,BMC,BERRY,redBUX,RAC,MCO,DLT,STX,SFU,TCOIN,RKT,MANA,OAK,SNM,FUN,WRC,BCAT,VRA,CFTY,TNT,PROPS,OMG,ANT,AE,EDO,SETH,WT,TIOX,CMCT,ENJ,EVX,KICK,COV,ZUP,PLR,VEE,BDG,KEY,STT,U42,UTK,AID,AVT,IMPCN,TFLEX,SLX,PLA,ISR,GARD,FLUZ,BAX,RVT,CSP,HOLO,MCAP,THO,VLR,TFD,WBBC,ELY,DBCCOIN,LA,OAX,DAV,ETH,OST,DMT,GLDR,IHT,FLP,CTR,ILCT,BEX,CTLX,ATOM,NAVI,CEDEX,EVC,TPAY,WAVES,WELL,WHN,LYK,eQUAD,HHEM,GENE,APPC,MASP,LAMB,ABYSS,QTUM,PHX,EKO,DTR,CPAY,COFI,CEEK,BIT,AIR,ATB,CFI,HQX,PRO,PIX,NEU,GES,ART,NIM,MYST,ICOS,SLY,ORS,HST,FOAM,DEB,OSA,TMT,GFT,LEV,COB,TKN,HGS,GNO,GLA,DAOC,NPX,BOS,XCD,RLC,VERI,ADB,LCK,LCS,EARTH,MOAT,BNTN,FSBT,SUB,WLK,HOLD,DTH,ELI,NRN,CIX100,PST,DNO,ACAT,ROX,VIB,FIII,ICN,MFG,CJT,BCNX,REAL,CSNO,XYO,SAN,PTOY,MTRC,XRL,TAU,POE,KRM,GBXT,BCNA,BCAP,IMVR,DIM,ESTATE,BON,ARAW,IND,VCN,ADM,EXY,DNT,AMO,CPY,ADX,GC,HAC,PPT,MTL,BITX,CAS,DRGN,PAN,CUZ,PKT,SEAL,SHPING,GNT,HVN,LED,YMZ,LTA,CTX,EBC,BITCAR,GAMB,GMA,STAC,DUSK,GENS,SRXIO,DTN,PBT,KEP,ADT,BBI,MNTP,CAN,TAAS,LWF,DAY,CCOS,DAT,SNGLS,CDT,KNW,AEN,WIZ,BFC,SHP,ZRC,EQUI,TIX,IXT,ERT,MLT,SPX,VTM,PROOF,ECHT,INDI,SCL,UBEX,HBT,TIE,MAID,WGR,LSK,GBE,ATL,ETRNT,ITM,ARR,LOCI,DLA,MIO,FNX,AZ,TFL,GJC,JVY,SCRM,MOLK,DGD,1ST,X8X,GUAR,TIME,AUC,EON,ORBIS,HGT,HMQ,XID,REP,MSP,VIN,STA,DRP,ALX,TAN,GUP,JOY,ACE,VZT,VNS,CAPP,XELS,AIC,MEM,REPUX,AMP,TRW,TRST,ARN,XBB,OXY,SRCH,PPY,ECOB,FUNDP,ETT,HETA,LYM,FLOT,DENT,DCT,QAU,XRM,PLC,SFT,COIN,SRNT,NVST,PINMO,CVCOIN,NEO,ADST,DTX,IPT,DIP,GBA,BTS,PKC,CHT,CHX,LUN,JOYT,GRO,CLIN,SKIN,MNRB,QRL,MOS,MOBU,NRX,COTI,YUM,MYDFS,WINS,H2O,MLN,IAG,VESTA,OSF,GBTC,MYB,TASH,CRON,SUR,T4M,CAP,EDG,ICOO,VANM,PSK,ALTOCAR,PING,ICE,FNP,DNN,ICST,LNT,PHM,UNITY,RCC,VRT,BCCOIN,OCEANT,MT,IFT,COS,LAT,CRL,ILT,SAT,STU,SNOV,PRIX,HMT,ARNA,COR,WINGS,LGD,CYBR,AXIS,KMD,ITT,MTX,OMI,LYQD,GAI,ENCX,DDF,WRL,ETE,XCP,GMR,TOSS,ET4,VSL,ETKN,TKT,SNC,PYP,RYZ,FDX,ATFS,GEA,LNK,TJA,SND,BTRM,IGTT,AMBT,FILL,VOISE,AUDC,REA,AUK,ATTR,GIM,CRS,DNA,NEBL,CTW,BETHER,AUN,DHT,LKK,ETBS,FYN,INCNT,BAY,DTB,TRIP,ADL,ADUX,GUESS,MBI,PLU,DRC,ARK,SRC,EMT,HDG,SRX,KEX,FFCT,KVNT,PART,QVT,DGPT,COT,SREUR,ROCK,KAPU,TUT,ENK,PQT,CWEX,STRAT,RKC,NFN,SWARM,NBX,WAND,TFC,DTRC,SAF,OMNI,MAT,HBX,EMN,EJAC,FNTB,SPEND,FOXT,GOLOS,SJCX,DSLA,ATON,UMC,AVA,PRP,SDAO,NXC,KEN,VIA,TKR,CHK,VEGA,ORI,ZOPT,TWC,RIYA,CREA,GXC,ROCK2,JDC,DAR,DTCT,WEB,PERU,JSE,PGL,HELIOS,OTX,MC,ODMC,GGS,CFT,ABC,VTOS,CCT,FLLW,SGN,SIFT,CRTM,PRM,CO2,BOU,ITR,SNK,CZC,AHT,AGVC,XRX,SYC,3DES,LTCH,CPL,NIMFA,TRAVEL,SCOR,BNR,TKS,UET,XTRA,MNM,XLC,XCJ,PLMT,MEDI,CWX,IWT,PSB,SPORTG,XSPEC,ICOB,SMNX,KRP,NXT,EQ,ROK,AFCT,TRIBE,Z2,DFBT,OXY2,MIOTA,ZYM,ZUC,ZRX,ZNT,ZNAQ,ZNA,ZIX,ZILLA,ZEROB,ZEEW,ZCHN,ZCC1,ZAZA,ZAB,YSH,YPTO,YDY,YBT,YANU,YACHTCO,XUC,XTN,XSB,XRK,XRF,XRED,XRBT,XR,XPX,XPT,XPR,XPL,XOS,XNT,XIM,XGH,XEP,XDT,XCZ,XBX,XBOND,XBANK,XAL,WYR,WXT,WUG,WU,WTXH,WTT,WTL,WSH,WRT,WPT,WPP,WOWX,WORK,WOM,WMK,WMD,WMB,WLME,WIIX,WICC&tsym=USD"
r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
data=json.loads(r.text)
print(data)
```

---

If you want to use your code however you might not get all the values because page is rendered by javascripts.Use selenium or my above solution to get expected result. to get all links just use `soup.find_all('a')`
`
Here is the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url= "https://www.cryptocompare.com/ico/#/completed"
r=session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

coin_name_list_items = soup.find_all('a')
```

Comment: thanks so much and both methods work! However, I was only able to pull out information for 414 coins listed on the website, while there are 1414 coins in total. Is there anyway I can access all of them?